# Python Fill Empty Rows with Other Columns based on Matching

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to fill empty columns with the same data if certain other columns match.

For example:

| ID | ID_2 | CIRCUIT | E-COM1 | E-COM2 | E-RES1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45345 | 342425 | 4453 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 45345 | 342425 | 4453 |  |  |  |

I'd like to fill E-COM1, E-COM2, and E-RES1 with the same values as in the first row IF the ID, ID_2 and CIRCUIT are the same. I'd tried using .fillna but am getting odd results.

Thanks!

Comment: `df[['E-COM1','E-COM2','E-RES1']]=df.groupby(['ID', 'ID_2', 'CIRCUIT'])[['E-COM1','E-COM2','E-RES1']].ffill()`